# is it safe or unsafe to potentially see their PHP session_id()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, security, session

On my site, I have some jquery which is making a post request from my login form to my API. Here is the jquery:

```
function doLogin()
{
  var userEmail = $("#email").val();
  var userPassword = $("#password").val();

  $.post(
    "https://api.linkenfest.co.uk/access/login/<?= $referrer ?>",
    {
      email: userEmail,
      password: userPassword
    }
  ).done(function( data ){
    var status   = data.data.status;
    var referrer = data.data.referrer;
    var message  = data.data.message;
    var session  = data.data.session;

    alert( message );

    if( status == 200 ){
      window.location.replace( referrer + "?session=" + session );
    }
  }
);
```

On returning a success, the response from my api looks like this:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "data":{
          "status": 200,
          "referrer": "page.php",
          "message": "Successful login",
          "session": "o3vo1uram0k2mojmbd45pmicr2"
      }
}
```

As you can see from my response, it includes the value obtained from php `session_id()`

I would like to find out if giving this information to the user opens up for a security vulnerability on the site.

The session ID value is used to start the session after `window.location.reload`

Thanks.

Comment: The session ID is normally provided to the client via a cookie. The client has to know it in order to identity what session it's associated with. If the client doesn't know its own session ID, then sessions become useless.

Comment: So they'd be able to see it even if I wasn't showing it in the response

Comment: Yep, by inspecting the site's cookies. (Or the headers on the request that sets them.)

Comment: Note also that unless you're doing nonstandard trickery, you'll need to drop the id into a cookie with the same name that PHP is expecting it to be in.

Comment: Yeah, it's working, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't going to make more problems.

Comment: Why would you want to send it in the first place? Session cookies are typically `httpOnly` protected whereas ajax can easily be intercepted by an xxs script

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out in comments, the client getting the session id is the standard way to manage sessions - how else could it send it in subsequent requests? But it does matter how the client receives it.

Note that the code above is very likely vulnerable.

1. `"https://api.linkenfest.co.uk/access/login/<?= $referrer ?>"` - This is reflected XSS if $referrer is the Referer header from the request. As it is in a Javascript context, it is not enough to simply html encode, you need javascript encoding.
2. `window.location.replace( referrer + "?session=" + session )` - This technically is an open redirect to the referrer parameter. It is not easy to exploit though. The best practice would still be to validate it (preferably on the server - which might already be in place).
3. Weak session management, session id is available to Javascript. While in some cases this is acceptable, accepting this risk should be a conscious decision. A session id should normally (and traditionally) be set in an httpOnly cookie. One exception when this can't be done is when a token needs to be sent to a different origin. But in that case it's not a session id semantically, and a proper SSO solution should be in place.
4. A session id is sensitive information, and as such, should not be sent in the url. The problem with the url is that it gets logged in multiple places (the user's browser will remember it and save it to disk, it will get logged on intermediate proxies, and in the target server's logs. These are all places from where an attacker might be able to get it. It's best to not send sensitive information in the url, but either in a header (a cookie is also just a header), or the request body is also ok if needed.
5. The destination url (api.linkenfest.co.uk) is vulnerable to login csrf if it allows you to log in this way.

Also looking at this from a broader perspective, what I guess you are doing is using the api as an identity provider to log your user in. For this purpose you should use a standard protocol like OpenID Connect, and not reinvent the wheel, because as you can see above, it is not at all straightforward.